# Conditional processing with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Im doing some scraping from web. And want that some data get saved, only if we find some tags inside it. My code looks like this:

```
def process
    doc = HTTParty.get("https://www.remotelyawesomejobs.com/jobs")
    @parse_page ||= Nokogiri::HTML(doc)
    @all_jobs = @parse_page.css(".job")
    @all_jobs.children.each do |job|
       @url =  @job_parse_page.at_css("h2 a")['href'] 
    end
end
```

The problem here. When Im doing

```
@url = job_parse_page.at_css("h2 a")['href']
```

Sometimes the children on the lasso doesnt have a css ("h2 a") and the app breaks and throws an error.

How is the best way to do "Hey. If you dont have a "h2 and a" on your DOM, just go to the next element? But if you have, do some other processing?

Comment: Why not use Nokogiri to grab the elements directly? `css('.job h2 a')`?

Comment: Also why are you calling `children` on the `.job` collection?

Comment: The page has a lot of divs with class "job". So I want that, for each div, make a processing. Was it clear?

Comment: "lasso"? Are you referring to the "at" ("`@`")?

Comment: When asking we need the smallest example of input data (HTML) that duplicates the problem in the question itself. Don't ask us to retrieve data from an unknown site; help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Loops in Ruby can be advanced using the `next` keyword. So you could do something like this:

```
@all_jobs.each do |job|
  link = job.at_css("h2 a")
  next unless link

  @url = link['href']
  ... 
end
```

Comment: Hey Casper. The problem here is that this attribution breaks the code (because it doesnt have a h2 on it. link = @job_parse_page.at_css("h2 a")

Comment: `next unless link`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
@url = job_parse_page.at_css("h2 a,[href]")['href'] rescue 'no href!'
```

That will look for the h2 a, then anything with a href attribute, and rescue with 'no href!'